# Is it possible to leave the cell containing the result Blank in an IF(OR( Formula when no data was yet inputed

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Basically, I am trying to get a Blank cell if neither of the targeted cells contain data.

My formula goes as follows: `=IF(OR(H2="No",J2="No"),"Yes","No")`

So, I want that if either the **H** column or the **J** column contains **No**, it will return **Yes** in the **K** column. In the event that both columns contain Yes, then the **K** row will result in **No**

The problem is that since this formula considers a blank space in both **H** and **J** Rows to be a FALSE Result, it automatically fills in the **K** row with **No** until I change the data in the **H** or **J** row.

Any tampering of my formula with commands such as `ifblank` have not yet yielded any positive results.

Hopefully, my explanation was detailed enough. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide some test data? The command `IFBLANK` doesn't exist, do you mean `ISBLANK`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like

```
=IF(AND(ISBLANK(H2),ISBLANK(J2)), "", IF(OR(H2="No",J2="No"), "Yes", "No"))
```

should do it.

Comment: I think your first OR should be an AND.  OP wants a result if one of the fields has a value.

Comment: @mcalex I guess you’re probably right. I (still) find the question a little confusing — and incomplete, as it doesn’t explicitly state that the cells can only contain blank, **No** and **Yes**, nor does it say how other values (e.g., **Maybe**, **Orange** or **Tiger**) should be handled — but I guess I just didn’t try hard enough the first time I read it, and so I misunderstood it. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Sorry, didn't think about that. It is only Blank, **Yes** and **No**. The cells are set to give only those possible answers via a drop down list.

Also, your formula worked just perfectly! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of clarity, I will use TRUE / FALSE instead of "Yes" / "No" as the result in column K.

List of requirements

- If both cells H2 **and** J2 contain no data / are blank, the result in K2 must also be blank
- If both cells H2 **and** J2 contain "Yes", the result in K2 must be FALSE
- In all other cases, the result in K2 must be TRUE

To achieve the above goal, in Excel 2016 with an Office 365 subscription. you can use the [IFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFS-function-36329a26-37b2-467c-972b-4a39bd951d45).

```
=IFERROR(IFS(AND(ISBLANK(H2),ISBLANK(J2)),"",AND(H2="Yes",J2="Yes"),FALSE),TRUE)
```

Not my best work, but it does give you this result
[image: Excel data showing results achieved]

Comment: I like your ansswer as well. Just adapted it as it wasnt exactly what i needed.

`=IF(IFS(AND(ISBLANK(H2),ISBLANK(J2)),"",AND(H2="Yes",OR(J2="Yes")),"Yes"),"No")`

Worked just fine after this tuning! Thanks for that solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `COUNTA` to test whether the cells are populated or not, e.g. if you want the formula to return a blank only if **neither** cell is populated

`=IF(COUNTA(H2,J2)=0,"",IF(OR(H2="No",J2="No"),"Yes","No"))`

....or to return a blank unless **both** cells are populated

`=IF(COUNTA(H2,J2)<2,"",IF(OR(H2="No",J2="No"),"Yes","No"))`

Answer (score 0):

Purposely I’ve posting this Answer to raise my points.

Question posted by @Daghanoth has 3 parts.

1. I am trying to get a Blank cell if neither of the targeted cells contain data.
2. I want that if either the H column or the J column contains No, it will return Yes in the K.
3. In the event that both columns contain Yes, then the K row will result in No.

**Let me first discuss my recent formula is,**

=IF(AND(ISBLANK(I261),ISBLANK(J261))," ",IF(OR(I261="No",J261="No"),"Yes",IF(AND(I261="Yes",J261="Yes"),"No","Out of Data")))

Part 1 is for Criteria 1 if TRUE.   =IF(AND(ISBLANK(I261),ISBLANK(J261))," ",

Part 2 is for Criteria 2 if TRUE.   ,IF(OR(I261="No",J261="No"),"Yes",

Part 3 for Criteria 3   if TRUE.   ,IF(AND(I261="Yes",J261="Yes"),"No","

Part 4  if None of the Criteria is TRUE.   ,"Out of Data"))).

**NB:** Deliberately I’ve written ‘Out of Data’ coz if I put BLANK then will create confusion since been used for Criteria 1.

If I put Comma will reflect ZERO reason is simple “Whenever we use any Logical Operators (AND, XOR, NOT, OR), if any cells is empty, such values are ignored”.

To test this put YES in 1 cell and keep other BLANK.

My previous Formula which I called an IMPROVISED,

=IF(AND(I261="No",J261="No"),"Both r No",IF(AND(I261="",J261="No"),"I261 is Blank",IF(AND(I261="No",J261=""),"J261 is Blank",IF(AND(I261="",J261=""),"Both Blank","Not Bank"))))

Has different captions but is working as **GMan & Barry's** Formulas are.

**Now I would like to take on FORMULA posted by G-Man**

IF(OR(ISBLANK(H2),ISBLANK(J2)), "BL", IF(OR(H2="No",J2="No"), "Yes", "No"))

This Formula is meeting Criteria 1 & 2 but not the 3rd one. Shows NO if You put YES in both or in one or any Characters. Where the original query is NO when both has YES.

**Other one posted by Barry,,**

=IF(COUNTA(I261,J261)=0,"",IF(OR(I261="No",J261="No"),"Yes","No"))

=IF(COUNTA(I261,J261)<2,"",IF(OR(I261="No",J261="No"),"Yes","No"))

Both Formulas are not meeting the Criteria 3 and his 2nd Formula shows Blank Space if one cell has Yes and other is any!!

**Now the point is No One has even bothered about the Bug.**

Comment: I don't know why you use `,,` all the time. It has no meaning